# How to get the height and width of a picture in powerpoint using Applescript

Tags: image, applescript, powerpoint, shapes

Can anyone tell me how I can get the width and height of a shape (image) object in PowerPoint using Applescript?  I have tried many ways, but none work!  I load the image by:

```
    set thePicture to make new picture at end with properties {lock aspect ratio:true, file name:item idx of HAImageNames}
```

Any help or advice will be greatly appreciated.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem.  I as trying:

```
    set x to width of thePicture
```

Apparently "x" is a special variable/name.  When I tried:

```
    set xx to width of thePicture
```

This worked as expected.